# Compiling mono-2.6 (or later) on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I am having to building mono from sources, since the Ubuntu package from badgerports is outdated (does not support .Net 4.0)

This is what I have done so far (mostly following instructions [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README)):

1. cloned mono git repository
2. switched to branch tagged 2.6 (git checkout mono-2-6)
3. installed minimal mono on my machine so mono and mcs are available on machine
4. run ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
5. run make

After a few modules compile correctly, I get this error:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/oompah/work/dev/mono/mono/mini'
CC  mini.lo
CC  liveness.lo
liveness.c: In function ‘mono_liveness_handle_exception_clauses’:
liveness.c:137: error: ‘MonoCompile’ has no member named ‘header’
make[4]: *** [liveness.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/oompah/work/dev/mono/mono/mini'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have looked at the offending code, and indeed a header member is being accessed ...

```
void
mono_liveness_handle_exception_clauses (MonoCompile *cfg)
{
        MonoBasicBlock *bb;
        GSList *visited = NULL;
        MonoMethodHeader *header = cfg->header;

        ...
}
```

Has anyone managed to build mono-2.6 (or later) on Ubuntu?

Comment: Why oh why are you trying to compile 2.6 if you need .Net 4.0 support? For this you want either _master_ or 2.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [scripts provided at integratedwebsystems](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/02/mono-2-10-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/) successfully to compile a recent version of mono on my system and run .net 4.0 applications.

an [improved version of the script](https://github.com/firegrass/mono-installer-script) can be found on firegrass' github account

Comment: The improved script broke down half way through the build. The first script built a "parallel install" - and it was a beatch to get build monodevelop. In the end, I scrapped both scripts and built both from tarbars on mono.. But I'll accept your answer anyway - since it set me on the right path (I looked at what the script was doing/trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

Joe Shields is packaging Mono 2.10 and is patching everything to default to .NET 4.0 for Ubuntu, you might want to poke him on twitter @directhex.